# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}$ divergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence

How to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}\bigg)$$ is divergent? I tried multiplying by the conjugate.
I got $$({\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}})({\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}})$$
How to prove that it is divergent? Is there any way to prove it by comparison test?

Comment: The terms of the series have to go to zero. Does this happen?

Comment: It doesn't. Thank you. I completely forgot to always check the necessary condition for the convergence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}=2
$$
and $2\neq0$, your series diverges.

Comment: yes... the necessary condition for the convergence... I forgot to firstly check it... Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind to accept my answer?

Comment: yes, sure. Sorry, I'm new here and I didn't know about it.